# Is this a valid sql Statement? Or is there a better alternative for this?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization, where-clause

The sql statement is:

```
SELECT * FROM support_chat WHERE (`from`=? AND `to`=?) OR (`from`=? AND `to`=?);
```

Or is there an alternative for this sql statement? And, is this sql statement valid (I think it is, but please tell me)?

Just in case:
My MySQL version is 8.0.22 (Installed from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads, source distro with boost for linux)

Comment: Is this a test about an unordered pair?  That is, are `from` and `to` always swapped in the second part of the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me use literal values rather than parameters, so the syntax is clearer. You seem to want:

```
where (`from` = 1 AND `to` = 2) OR (`from` = 2 AND `to` = 1)
```

This works, and (probably!) dos what you want. You could also phrase the logic tuple equality, which shortens the condition:

```
where (`from`, `to`) in ((1, 2), (2, 1))
```

This is likely to be more efficient than your original code, especially if you have an index on `(from, to)`.

Or, if you don't want to repeat the parameters:

```
where (1, 2) in ((`from`, `to`), (`to`, `from`))
```

An alternative uses `least()` and `greatest()`:

```
where least(`from`, `to`) = 1 and greatest(`from`, `to`) = 2
```

This would take advantage of an index on expressions, which is supported in very recent versions of MySQL:

```
create index idx_support_chat on support_chat((least(`from`, `to`)), (greatest(`from`, `to`)));
```

Comment: is ```where (`from` = 1 AND `to` = 2) OR (`from` = 2 AND `to` = 1)``` valid first of all? for sure?

Comment: I do have sql knowledge, but i want to be careful of certain things.

Comment: Is ```where (`from` = 1 AND `to` = 2) OR (`from` = 2 AND `to` = 1)``` valid first of all?

Comment: @WebTestingRL If it isn't valid it'll trigger a syntax error. Whether it's *correct* or not depends on whether the logic corresponds with your goals.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Oof, that solves my weird sense that something might be offf

Comment: Row constructors were not optimized until version 5.7.3.  Before that, the index would not be used.  The example with `LEAST()` is not sargeable, so it will require a table scan unless you have a new enough version to handle the 'functional' indexes.